# Why is my functional test getting the meta tag http-equiv='refresh' and then quitting?

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

When I run a simple functional test to get (for example) the users/signIn page, I'm getting this:

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=https://localhost/index.php/users/signIn"/></head></html>
```

and then the functional test just stops. It happens in other functional tests too, but not on every request. Other tests will run fine, then when it gets to a certain request in the test, it will get that response (with the requested URL in the content attribute), and stop.

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

These functional tests used to work, but I just got this project back from another development company and I don't have an idea of *where* to start looking for the changes. Of course I can do diffs on the files with the version control, but I don't know where to start. Thanks for any leads!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argh, found it quicker than I thought.

The SSL filter was turned on, and needs to be disabled for the test environment. They had removed the test environment from app.yml.

```
test:
    disable_sslfilter: true
```